# Java PokerHand method

Tags: java, junit, poker

I'm making a Poker Hand code that looks for various poker hands in a hand. I am writing tests after i have implemented each method.

I have wrote isFlush() code which tests if the hand is a flush.

```
public boolean isFlush()
{

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (cards.get(i).getSuit() == cards.get(i + 1).getSuit())
    {
        return true;
}
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the corresponding test, which builds successfully but the test actually fails. It says expected false but is true. What have i done wrong in the code which doesn’t test for a flush properly?

```
@Test public void testIsFlush()
{

 pokerHand.add(aceClubs);
 pokerHand.add(kingSpades);
 pokerHand.add(threeClubs);
 pokerHand.add(fourClubs);
 pokerHand.add(fiveClubs);

 assertEquals(false, pokerHand.isFlush());
 }
```

Comment: What kind of value does getSuit() return? Also, your isFlush() function will return true whenever two cards next to each other are the same suit.

Comment: it returns "C, D, H, S" a string, and how do i make it check all 5 cards? @djebeeb

Comment: Your true/false conditions are backward: you should early-return false on any mismatch, and only return true if the loop finishes.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean isFlush()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if( !cards.get(i).getSuit().equals(cards.get(i + 1).getSuit()) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Its better to check if two consecutive cards are not equal in suit.

Answer (score 0):

i assume suit is a string..  so would bebetter compare them with equals method instead ==.
On theother hand your for method, if the first two cards have same suit will return always true withoutchecking the other cards... You should rewrite that method and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking only the first and second cards, since you return true immediately.  Check all the cards and `and` the values together.

Answer (score -1):

`for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)` Just checks the first 4 cards, you need 5 cards for a flush.

```
 if (cards.get(i).getSuit() == cards.get(i + 1).getSuit())
    {
        return true; }
    }
    return false; }
```

This will check just the first two cards, as it will return immediately after just checking cards 0 and 1.

Also, if you're checking the suit as strings, you should use `String.equals()`

**EDIT:** As requested, I'll provide a code sample.

```
public boolean isFlush()
{

boolean condition=true;
for (int i = 0; (i <4)&&condition; i++)
{
    if (!(cards.get(i).getSuit() == cards.get(i + 1).getSuit()))
    {
        condition=false;
    }

    }
return condition;}
```

Comment: You only need 4 comparisons; a hand of one card is always a "flush" since all cards suits are the same.

Comment: The problem remains, nonetheless, he's returning on the first iteration.

Comment: how do i edit it to return after checking all 5 cards? @Wazowski

Comment: Done @soph16578 , notice how the if statement condition is now reversed. As soon as it finds a discrepancy between cards suits, the for loop will stop.